# ios vacuum wrap UIView

Tags: ios

my UIView has a dynamic amount of views inside of it and also has a background color to it. I'm trying to tuck the UIView in around all the items, but it's not working.

`[self sizeToFit]` Seems to work just fine on a UILabel, but not on a UIView.

I know I can calculate the area manually by looping through all the subviews, but that just seems like too much work for something like this.

I'm hoping someone knows a simpler way.. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### UPDATE

If you're using auto layout, you can make your container view fit its subviews snugly.  Set up constraints between your container and its subviews, and set up constraints between the subviews and the container's superview, but **do not** set up constraints between the container and its superview.

### ORIGINAL

There's no built-in support for automatically shrink-wrapping a view around its subviews.

The `sizeToFit` method works by sending `[self sizeThatFits:self.bounds.size]`, then resizing itself based on the size returned by `sizeThatFits:`.

`UILabel` overrides the `sizeThatFits:` method to compute the size of its text in its font.

You will need make a custom `UIView` subclass and override `sizeThatFits:`.  It's pretty simple:

```
- (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size {
    CGRect rect = CGRectZero;
    for (UIView *subview in self.subviews)
        rect = CGRectUnion(rect, subview.frame);
    return rect.size;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a "dynamic" way. You see, resizing only works the way around, a subview ca be made to dynamicaly change it's size when a superview does.

Anyway, what you are describing as "too much work" is exactly (more or less) what sizeToFit does...